# Procedural texture on curved surface without distortion

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural, shader-nodes

I have generated a texture that always should have stripes oriented sidewards and stripes oriented downwards.

Like in that screenshot (artifacts are from fine lines):

[image]

But when I try to put the same texture on a curved surface it turns out like this; The vertical lines bend around a 90° angle in the middle of the object:

[image]

The surface it should be on is a rectengula plane, that is twisted on it's middle axis:

[image]
[image]

The horizontal lines are calculated with this setup (Mapping scale Z for repetitions) :
[image]

The vertical lines, which seem to bend are calculated the same way, but rotated by 90°:

[image]

I already put in the object-output of the texture coordinate node.
How can I straighten up the lines on no matter what surface, so they point downwards? I want the to have them to keep the same distance to each other and to it's objects edge.

Comment: This is a screenshot. The lines are just very fine.

Comment: Hi, apologies the image quality is insufficient and those looked like photos of a monitor. Either way please don't crop your images too tightly so we get some context. Showing the surrounding UI and complete objects some times helps us diagnose issues like being in the wrong modes, incorrect settings or selections.

Comment: Likewise attempting to diagnosing issues with shaders materials or textures without showing the corresponding node tree is a futile exercise. Please show your complete node tree, material settings and object topology of the shape of the object is affecting the expected result of the material appearance.

Comment: I edited the question, so it might be more insightful.

Comment: You may need to use UV texture coordinates - this will map the procedural texture to a 2D X/Y plane (as opposed to drawing its coordinates from 3D space). You will, of course, have to UV unwrap your object appropriately first.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bennet. This approach helped me with my situation. I will have to look into scaling uv indefinetly to match the pattern of smaller objects. But this is another story.